# Picture positioning with JS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanna create such a field with JS and Jquery.

Comment: Why not just apply a css border to the the img in that div?

Comment: every sector shall be accessible. becauce later shall flight a spacecraft over them.

Comment: all you need to do is define the `spacediv` at a width of 150 (50*3) + the width of the margin you want and then just apply margin to all images inside of `spacediv` using the css selector `spacediv img`

Answer (score 0):

This will enable you make id for every field. Thus you will be able to reference each field by id:

```
function drawSpace(x) {
    for ( var j = 0; j< x; j++) {
        for ( var i=0; i< x; i++) {
            $('#spacediv').append('<img src="Weltall_Feld.jpg" alt="WeltallFeld" id="field' + i + '_' + j + '"/>');
        }   
        $('#spacediv').append('<br />');
    }
}

<div id="spacediv"></div>
```